# .net core 3.0 appsettings.json per environment

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I want to read in an environment specific `appsettings.json` based on `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`.

The example Microsoft gives for startup.cs is as follows for core 3.0:

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

In previous versions, code I have seen to add an environmental specific `appsettings.json` is:

```cs
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

How would I change the standard Microsoft example to include this?

Comment: Nothing has really changed. You're looking at completely different samples. ASP.NET Core 2.x *also* used the same default configuration, [using a WebHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1) instead of a generic host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"environment specific appsettings.json based on ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"* is already done by convention by the call `CreateDefaultBuilder()` in your `Program.cs` file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#default-configuration

So you do not need to do anything else. Just set up your `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value

Comment: Is it safe to keep connection string information though?